# simple python yweather program, basically in it's documentation returns error 8

Tags: python-3.x

```
import yweather

W = yweather.Client()

MyHouse = W.fetch_woeid("T8T 0B2")
MyWeather = W.fetch_weather(MyHouse)

print(MyWeather)
```

> This is my program, it's the same as in the documentation (https://yweather.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1/usage.html) except the variable names and the location (T8T 0B2) this is my location, and therefore is correct but i get this error when i run the program:

```
...$ python weather.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 6, in <module>
    CedricsWeather = W.fetch_weather(CedricsHouse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yweather.py", line 180, in fetch_weather
    rss = self._fetch_xml(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yweather.py", line 344, in _fetch_xml
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url)) as f:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

> By the way this is running in python 3.6.1 and on the latest MacOs.
>   I did try to run exactly the same code as the documentation with the same woeid and got the same error.

Comment: It would look like the service has been abandoned by Yahoo, since `http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/` does not exist anymore (at least not at this moment). In case Yahoo has changed the url, you may want to file an issue with the project itself, at https://github.com/tsroten/yweather/issues .

Comment: i see. so is it just a useless nonfunctional module now?

Comment: oh, well. I did find something else though and IT as opposed to yweather works very well!

Comment: it's open weather maps

Comment: "import pyowm

W = pyowm.OWM("df40246eb98f6141115fc20f0674aad9")
myHouse = W.weather_at_place("St. albert,Canada") #56688831 is more precise
myWeather = myHouse.get_weather()

wind = myWeather.get_wind()
temperature = myWeather.get_temperature("celsius")

print("weather:\n")
print(myWeather)
print("\n\nwind:\n")
print(wind)
print("\n\ntemperature:\n")
print(temperature)
"